# switching xib's objective c iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, xib

I have this code that I believe should switch from one xib to another but it isn't working, no errors are occurring just nothing happens when I click on the button thats linked to the IBAction. Any ideas?

```
-(IBAction) startButton:(id) sender {

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:[[GameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameViewController" bundle:nil] animated:YES];



}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are not in a navigation interface. Thus `[self navigationController]` is nil, and a message to nil in Objective-C does nothing.

Comment: Ahh ok, how should I go about switching between the xibs then?

Comment: You could use a navigation interface! But the simplest most direct way is to use a presented view controller (`presentViewController...`).

Comment: By the way, here's my full discussion all about view controllers and all the stuff you can do with them: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html

Comment: presentViewController works perfectly, thank you very much. Also your link is very informative, think I will have a more detailed read through it later. Cheers